# How to select the nearest agent connected through another agent in a network in AnyLogic?

Tags: java, anylogic

In a model I have connected different agent types in a network through 'link to other agents' objects. I have used a function to create the network:

```
shopLink.connectTo(this.getNearestAgent(main.shops));
homeLink.connectTo(this.getNearestAgent(main.homes));
```

So each Factory-agent is connected to the nearest shop and home only. This function is called at the 'at startup' field within the Factory-agent type.

[image]

Let's assume the red agent types are factories, yellow represent shops, and green represent homes. Also assume that all Factory-agents contain Person-agents, and I want to send the Person-agents to the most nearby Shop-agent is connected to the Factory-agent. What Java code would I need to use to select the most nearby Shop-agent connected to the Factory-agent?

Comment: I think this is a graph problem. Therefore you can read this [blog post](https://www.baeldung.com/java-graphs). Otherwise it would be helpful to know what you do already? Did you write some code?

Comment: share some more details about your actual connections setup in the Factory agent type and we can help ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your Person agents exist inside a Factory parent agent, and you have connections as shown, then it depends how your connections are set up in Factory:

(a) If Factory's default `connections` Link to Agents object contains *only* Shop agent connections, use

`getNearestAgent(factory.getConnections())`

(b) If Factory's shop connections are in a special Link to Agents object (say `shopConnections`) then use

`getNearestAgent(factory.shopConnections.getConnections())`

(c) If you've mixed connections to all other agent types (shops, factories, etc.) in Factory's default `connections` Link to Agents you'll have to filter that list first to include only Shop agents so

`(Shop) getNearestAgent(filter(factory.getConnections(), f -> f instanceof Shop))`

(There are Java subtleties in terms of why case (c) requires the `(Shop)` bit at the start, which is a Java cast, but (a) doesn't. It's to do with the fact that both `getNearestAgent` and `getConnections` are [generic methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html), and [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html) is being used.)

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, Stuart. It is much appreciated. I am using approach (b), and I managed to get it working as I intended.